# Character stops moving in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in unity where when I move my character it stops moving and I have to move to a different direction and then return to the original direction to be able to move here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed=5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Debug.Log(horizontal);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity= new Vector2(speed*horizontal,rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

_ The horizontal input works normally when the problem happen
_ There is no specific location where the character gets stops

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you tried with different controllers/input devices to make sure it is not a hardware issue?

Comment: No;l but I will if you want

Comment: I tried but same problem

Comment: Two things come to mind. Sometimes this can happen when walking between 2 colliders even if they seem perfectly aligned. The solution could be composite collider or tilemap (which still does combining of tile collders). The second thing could be some other code interfering with movement.

Comment: I'm working already with tilemap but it's seems like a computer problem. I'm obviously not an expert but I think it happens when the computer lags for a little bit. My computer is kinda weak tbh. Can I change my code or sm in a way that fixes this problem?

Comment: btw this problem happens in every project I make I tried to change the script but it didn't work and it might be an input device problem as you said but if it was how can I fix it? I got no other input devices tbh. and when I ran a 2D game in my computer i never encountered this problem. I think it also happened when I used another game engine called godot.